# Synonymize [flow3] and [typo3-flow]?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

The TYPO3-related php framework FLOW3 has been renamed a few weeks ago to TYPO3-FLOW. Can someone introduce a new tag [typo3-flow](/questions/tagged/typo3-flow) and set it as a synonym to [flow3](/questions/tagged/flow3)?

Sources:

- [The TYPO3 Family - A Brand New Way](http://typo3.org/the-brand/the-way-to-the-new-branding/)
- [Wikipedia on FLOW3 / TYPO3 Flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOW3)

Answer (score 3):

The information you supplied seemed good, so I just did a manual re-tag of all questions tagged [flow3](/questions/tagged/flow3) (26) to [typo3-flow](/questions/tagged/typo3-flow), and copied over the tag wiki. I have no reputation under that tag, however, so I cannot suggest a synonym.

Comment: Thanks. Only problem: The list at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flow3 is now empty. Not good for people who bookmarked the page or search for the old tag.

Comment: @Mateng like I said, I don't have any rep in that tag to make it a possible synonym. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Richard, but who can? Can you help directing this to the right user?

Comment: @Mateng any mod should be able to do that. I've flagged my answer for moderator attention so maybe that will help.

Comment: @Mateng All done. :)